# Modifying custom attributes in XML file, in a

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom attribute in a subview class defined in XML file:

```
    <com.mysubView>
    android:id="@+id/board"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    cus:Count="0"
    />
```

I would like to be able to access it main_activity.java to set a value to Count like this:

```
findViewById(R.id.board).setCount(10);
```

Is it possible?

Note: attrs.xml is already populated with corresponding stylable.

[Here is a related article on custom attributes](http://knowledgefolders.com/akc/display?url=DisplayNoteIMPURL&reportId=4169&ownerUserId=satya)
Here is constructor to the sub-view class:

```
public MySubView (Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(c, attrs);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the value of count. Of course you need a method with signature `setCount(int)`, defined inside `mysubView`, and you will have to cast the return result of `findViewById` to `mysubView`

```
((mysubView)findViewById(R.id.board)).setCount(10);
```

this way you will able to change any specific property/behaviour you defined in `mysubView`

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What would the method implementation would look like? which variable should I be accessing? for example: do I just get the int hand-off directly to the method with the signature? where do I assign it to?

Comment: did your write the View's subclass?

Comment: yeah. tested and working. I am adding the void setCount(int test) to it now. I dunno what to assign it to. Count is not available.

Comment: can you post the the constructor of your CustomView ?

Comment: public MySubView (Context c, AttributeSet attrs) {
           super(c, attrs);
       }

Comment: please do a Gist with the whole class